# Necrophiliacs: bring dead, unanswered questions back to life

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, unanswered-questions, necromancer-badge

I think many don't even know [Necromancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) exists.

Could an **easily accessible UI tab** be provided to highlight two month old questions with no answers and a score >= 0?  This would both enable people to find them and encourage answering to get a shiny silver badge.

Currently you have to craft a [special search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=420&tab=newest&q=answers:0%20votes:0%20closed:0) by answers:0, votes:0 (really means score >= 0), closed:0, sort by newest, and change to a specific page in the results.

Comment: This may be pre-empted by the general [homepage redesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69063/54262) for SO, but still applies to other SE sites.

Comment: +1, but for the record, Necrophilia and Necromancy have surprisingly little in common.

Comment: Especially if you consider the end result rather than the, hmm, material.

Comment: @MPe: I know; was just trying to have a bit of fun with the title. ;)

Comment: As an unrelated note, I highly appreciated the combination of the question title and the @Roger Pate's [current avatar](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/747f80616d1aa2504890e3b59947a9d6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG).

Comment: @MPelletier, the necromancer badge is for someone who profits from resurrecting old questions (5 upvotes). The necrophiliac badge would be for someone who touches dead questions for the sake of it. :)

Answer (score 5):

The query can be made much better ([run search on SO](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+votes%3A1..+closed%3A0+created%3A..2m)):

```
answers:0 votes:1.. closed:0 created:..2m
```

In general it means

- `answers:0` - has exactly 0 answers
- `votes:1..` - has 1 or more votes
- `closed:0` - is not closed
- `created:..2m` - created 2 months ago or earlier

When posted this answer it meant

> **search options**
>   not closed
>   score>= 1
>   answers 0
>   created .. 2016-09-15

PS: It would've been cool to get <kbd>Necromancer</kbd> badge on a question about it)))

Comment: @Glorfindel, updated an answer.

Comment: I don't think the votes option is necessary. It isn't mentioned in the [list of badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) that the question's score needs to be positive.

Comment: @Glorfindel, then why does the question contain "votes:0 (really means score >= 0)"? By some reason I thought that both question and answer have to be upvoted.

Comment: IDK, it has been six years since this question was asked and the criteria might have changed. IMHO, it is even more badge-worthy to provide a 5-score answer to a negative scoring question.

Comment: @Glorfindel, [Reversal](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) - Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score. This badge can be awarded multiple times. Don't think, it's easy to earn :)

Comment: That's a different league (and therefore a gold badge). I have some of them on Meta Stack Overflow.