# Necromancer badge given based on merged duplicate instead of master question

Tags: bug, merged-questions, necromancer-badge

The system awarded me Necromancer, attributing it to the fresh printed new question instead of the older decrepit master question it was merged into.

I earned the "Necromancer" badge because I "Answered a question more than 60 days later with a score of 5 or more."

I did not actually answer a question more than 60 days after it was asked. I just won the badge because the question had been merged with a previous one.

Shouldn't the system have this premise in consideration and not award badges like that?

Comment: probably an unplanned side effect of the new handling of duplicates.  Should this get a [meta-tag:bug] tag as well?

Comment: someone else might disagree with me so don't count on it staying.  But it does seem like a bug since you didn't really answer the old question.

Comment: Well, if in the end it turns out that it is not a bug, I just edited again :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Necromancer" is about the end result: an old question raised to new life with your well-received answer.

It's not about the *intention*, i.e. it's fine if you didn't post your answer out of love for old and dead questions, which in fact the system currently doesn't encourage. Someone joked that we should [encourage necrophiliacs too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69114/necrophiliacs-bring-dead-unanswered-questions-back-to-life). Maybe a new badge, to clarify the difference?

Comment: And this answer just got Necromancer! :)